# Laravel 5.1 nested complex query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make this query from few hours, but i can't make this query in laravel syntax

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw(
"
SELECT * FROM products AS P WHERE (`d` = $d)
            AND (`mis` BETWEEN $min_c AND $max_c)
            AND (`e` BETWEEN $e_min AND $e_max)
            AND p1 IN
                            (
                            SELECT p1
                            FROM autos AS A
                            WHERE (`ma` = $strma)
                            AND (`d` = $d )
                            AND (`mis` BETWEEN $min_c AND $max_c)
                            AND (`e` BETWEEN $e_min AND $e_max)
                            AND (`p1` = P.p1 )
                            AND (`p2` = P.p2 )
                            )
            AND p2 IN
                            (
                            SELECT p2
                            FROM autos AS A
                            WHERE (`ma` = $strma)
                            AND (`d` = $d )
                            AND (`mis` BETWEEN $min_c AND $max_c)
                            AND (`e` BETWEEN $e_min AND $e_max)
                            AND (`p1` = P.p1 )
                            AND (`p2` = P.p2 )
                            )
"             
));
```

I think i have to use 2 functions like

```
->whereIn(array('p1','p2'),
function($query){

...
}
function($query2){
...
}
)
```

But it's doesen't work
In what way can i ask this to database in laravel syntax?

Comment: What does happen? Is your problem on Mysql or on Laravel? Did you try the query directly on a MySql more direct interface? It is very unclear what is your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing 2 where in with 2 functions.

```
->whereIn('p1',function($query) use (...
->whereIn('p2',function($query2) use (...
```